# Sobolev-type estimate for irrational winding on a torus

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, sp.spectral-theory, irrational-numbers

Let $\mathbb{T} = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \}/_{x \mapsto x + 1, y \mapsto y + 1}$ be a real 2-torus. Let $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{T})$ be the subset of $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$ of functions $f : \mathbb{T} \to \mathbb{R}$, verifying $\int_{\mathbb{T}} f(x, y) dx dy = 0$. Consider a differentiation $\nabla_{irr} : \mathscr{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{T}) \to \mathscr{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{T})$ in an irrational direction, e.g. $\nabla_{irr}(f) = \frac{df}{dx} + \sqrt{2} \frac{df}{dy}$. Is it true that $\inf_{f \in \mathscr{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{T})} \frac{\|\nabla_{irr}(f)\|_{L^2}}{\| f \|_{L^2}} > 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the infimum equals zero.

In the spirit of Asaf's comment, try
$$
f(x,y)=e^{i(mx+ny)} .
$$
Then $\|f\|=1$, $\nabla_{irr} f = i(m+\alpha n) f$, with $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ (but it'll work for any irrational $\alpha$),
so $\|\nabla_{irr} f\|^2 = (m+\alpha n)^2$.

By [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), there are infinitely many $(m,n)$ with $|m+\alpha n| < 1/n$.